# Regex in SQL server, using characters' position

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the customers for which the second letter of the name is 'A'. My first guess is:

**select 
*
from 
customers
where
customers.name like '[A-Z]A%'**

But is there a general approach (for SQL Server) to find record by the nth letter, something like

**select 
*
from 
customers
where
customers.name like '[A-Z]{n,m}A%'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 2, 1) = 'A'
```

Add `UPPER` if there are inconsistent cases.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE SUBSTRING(UPPER(name), 2, 1) = 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also express this using `LIKE`:

```
where name like '_A%'
```

As a note, this is ANSI standard syntax and will work in any database.  `_` is the wildcard representing a single character.